# Extreme points of the closed ball of regular measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $X$ be a topological vector space and $E$ a subset of $X$. A point $x\in E$ is called a extreme point of $E$ if  there is no proper line segment contained in $E$ which contains $x$.

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $\mathrm{ball}M(K)$ the closed ball of (complex) regular measures on $K$. How to prove  that $\alpha \delta_x$ is an extreme point of $\mathrm{ball}M(K)$, where $\delta_x$ is Dirac measure?

I understand how to prove that $\delta_x$ is an extreme point of $P(K)$ the set of  probabilities on $K$. But in statement above difficulties  appear due to $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the unit ball, and that $|\alpha|=1$.

If
$$\tag1
\alpha\delta_x=t\,\mu_1+(1-t)\,\mu_2, 
$$
That is, for any $f\in C(K)$ you have
$$\tag2
f(x)=t\,\int_Kf\,d(\alpha^{-1}\mu_1)+(1-t)\int_Kf\,d(\alpha^{-1}\mu_2). 
$$
Using the real and imaginary parts and the Hahn decomposition, you can write
$$
\alpha^{-1}\mu_j=\mu_j^1-\mu_j^2+i(\mu_j^{3}-\mu_j^{4}),\qquad\qquad j=1,2.
$$
For $f\geq0$,  we get
$$\tag3
f(x)=t\,\int_Kf\,d\mu_1^1+(1-t)\int_Kf\,d\mu_2^1,
$$
$$\tag4
0=t\,\int_Kf\,d\mu_1^k+(1-t)\int_Kf\,d\mu_2^k,\qquad\qquad k=2,3,4.
$$
As this can be done for any $f\geq0$, from $(4)$ we get $\mu_j^k=0$  for $k=2,3,4$, and from $(3)$ we get (as in the probability case) $\mu_j^1=\delta_x$. Thus
$$
\mu_j=\alpha\,\mu_j=\alpha\,\delta_x.
$$